# How to resolve warning messages of type: No way to resolve conflict between DLLs

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, app-config

I have a Windows service application made with VB.NET under Visual Studio 2013 and using NET Framework 4.5. I am using Nuget in this project.

Once I build the solution (it builds successfully) I get below warning messages in the results window:

```
  No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and "Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" arbitrarily.
  No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" arbitrarily.
  No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" arbitrarily.
  No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
  No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from version "9.0.0.0" [] to version "11.0.0.0" [C:\MyProjects\WindowsServices\MyService\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3276: Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. 
  Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For further information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
```

I have been searching for information about this, and I have found some posts and blogs talking about that:

- [No Way to Resolve Conflict Between dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998452/no-way-to-resolve-conflict-between-dlls)
- [No Way to Resolve Conflict Between dlls](http://toformcode111.blogspot.com/2012/06/c-no-way-to-resolve-conflict-between.html)

I have tried to clean up all the references in the VB.NET project that were not being used but above warning messages continue appearing.

Also I have gone into Manage NuGet Packages but I have not seen any duplicate packages in the list.

I don't see the duplicates anywhere (vbproj project file, app.config, etc.). Where can I find those duplicates? Where are the duplicates? How to search for the duplicates?

Finally, I know there is another way to resolve those conflicts (I have not tried yet) and it consists on adding binding redirects for all the assemblies that are conflicted in the app.config file. For example, in case of ClosedXML DLL:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ClosedXML" publicKeyToken="fd1eb21b62ae805b" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.85.0.0" newVersion="0.85.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Instead of adding manually confliting assemblies in the app.config file, I know it can be done automatically by Visual Studio by adding the property entry below in the vbproj project file:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Anyway, I would like to resolve those conflicts without binding redirects for all the conflicted assemblies in the app.config file. So Is that possible? If so, how?

Also I have some other questions in mind:

1. Binding redirects for conflicted assemblies in the app.config file
   is a good practice?
2. Why those conflicts between assemblies happen? I do not understand it at all, so please could you explain me this?
3. What happens if I not resolve those conflicts and I ignore them (since solution is build successfully without errors)? Is it mandatory or highly recomended to resolve them for any kind of reason that I currently do not know?

Comment: If I were you, I would have created a new fresh projet and added the code files to it.

Comment: If you have any external dependencies (that aren't the base-level things like the report viewer and json), I'd double-check them.  They might be pulling in the older versions.  Also see Jon Skeet's article here https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/06/30/versioning-limitations-in-net/ which discusses some of the problems that arise with dependencies on the same underlying assembly through different paths (that may ask for different versions of that assembly).

Comment: Just add the binding redirects and make sure everything is up to date, move on with your life :)