# How to statically declare a type at compile time by AssemblyQualifiedName in C#

Tags: c#, assembly-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When must we use extern alias keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347260/when-must-we-use-extern-alias-keyword-in-c)

I have an assembly which is composed mostly of files shared from other projects in the solution.  In other words, the whole solution would be about 10 MB, but I export a small subset of that functionality into a separate 200 KB assembly.  All the projects in the solution are in the NUnit test project except the UI.

The problem is, I went to add a test for one of the shared files, and I got the following error:

```
The type 'xxx' exists in both 'c:\path\to\project\Logic.dll'
and 'c:\path\to\project\Exported.dll'.
```

I know I can use reflection and provide an assembly qualified name, or I could remove the exported assembly tests into a separate project, but both would be a pain.  I simply want to specify to use the version of xxx in the Logic.dll at compile time.  Is it possible to specify which version of the Type to use at compile time, so it looks like this:

```
xxx blah = new xxx();
blah.DoSomething(123);
```

instead of:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("Logic.xxx, Logic");
object blah = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
t.GetMethod("DoSomething").Invoke(blah, new object[] { 123 });
```

Comment: Can't you just put 'xxx' in a different Namespace?  You would then access it by namespace.xxx blah = new namespace.xxx();

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a duplicate, because I would have to know that extern alias even exists to be able to search on it.  But I would accept that as the answer if you post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant's comment is the correct answer:  "extern alias" is what I was looking for, and the answers in [When must we use extern alias keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347260/when-must-we-use-extern-alias-keyword-in-c) give good pointers to how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the reference based on the namespace the object class you want is located. Something along the lines of this:

`LogicNamespace.XXX blah = new LogicNamespace.XXX();`

Comment: They can't have different namespaces because the file in the exported library is the exact same file in the main project, it's just a link.  I don't want to maintain two copies.

Comment: Most likely unrelated answer - I believe OP wants to distinguish 2 types build from the same source but coming from 2 different assemblies. So namespace+type name are the same, the only difference is assembly name.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that is correct.  Hans Passant's answer is exactly what I was looking for but he didn't post it where I can accept it.